# Prevent maxLength on number input from constantly changing value on last number?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have an input field within ReactJS like so:

```
  <input
    type="number"
    onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
    maxLength={3}
    min="0"
    max="999"
    step=".1"
    onPaste={handlePaste}
  />
```

Here are the associated functions for that input:

```
function handleKeyPress(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length > e.target.maxLength) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.maxLength);
  }

  const key = e.key;
  if (!allowChars(key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function allowChars(charValue) {
  const acceptedKeys = '0123456789';
  return acceptedKeys.indexOf(charValue) > -1;
}

function handlePaste(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Now every time I reach 3 characters, a 4th character is able to be typed constantly. Please see the attached GIF for an example:

[image: input number fail]

Any ideas on how I can prevent this? I just want the input field to have a max of 3 characters, so the 4th character should not even show up.

Comment: Why don't you jut use `max=999`?

Comment: I am doing that. That is so the value does not exceed 999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in this code fragment:

```
 if (e.target.value.length > e.target.maxLength) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.maxLength);
 }
```

Change it to:

```
if (e.target.value.length >= e.target.maxLength) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.maxLength);
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
}
```

```js
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.target.value.length >= e.target.maxLength) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.maxLength);
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    const key = e.key;
    if (!allowChars(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function allowChars(charValue) {
    const acceptedKeys = '0123456789';
    return acceptedKeys.indexOf(charValue) > -1;
}

function handlePaste(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input
        type="number"
        onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"
        maxLength="3"
        min="0"
        max="999"
        step=".1"
        onPaste="handlePaste(event)"
        />
```